# CentOS - Ruby - Executable host ruby is required

Tags: centos, ruby

I am trying to compile ruby (v1.9.2) on a CentOS 5.6 system (kernel v2.6.18-238.12.1.el5), but keep getting a "executable host ruby is required" error message during make.

Here are the steps:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ruby
make
```

I get the following error (in entirety):

```
echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false ./tool/generic_erb.rb -c -o known_errors.inc ./template/known_errors.inc.tmpl ./defs/known_errors.def
executable host ruby is required. use --with-baseruby option.
```

I read the description of what the '--with-baseruby' option does, but it seems circular, b/c I am trying to install ruby. So do I need to do something like:

```
--with-baseruby=/usr/local/ruby/... ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be related to v1.9.2, I was able to compile and make v1.8.7 with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ruby 1.9.X** requires a ruby version to be installed.

I know, it sucks, it makes no sense but it works like that. You can have an older **Ruby 1.9.X** or compile a **Ruby 1.8.X** (that does not have this requirement).

So:

- Install **Ruby 1.8.X**
- Install **Ruby 1.9.X**
- Remove **Ruby 1.8.X** (if it bothers you)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to v1.9.2, I was able to compile and make v1.8.7 with no issues.

Also, I just recently started the process of upgrading my servers from CentOS 5.6 to 6.0 and found this issue didn't not happen again when trying to install ruby v1.9.x+.